# Using Inkscape 1.3, I cannot find where to apply a "Simplify" path effect

Tags: inkscape, path

Using Inkscape 1.3, I cannot find where to apply a "Simplify" path effect. Nothing comes down on "Add Live Path Effect" menu, nor is there any Apply button. See attached screenshot.

Comment: Check if you have selected more than one item, The effect doesn't appear at all if you are trying to apply it to several objects in the same time. Group the items or select them one by one. If your group contains text or bitmap images the effect appears, but only paths and preset shapes are affected.

Comment: @Abuabapplipbleable - that's a very good point, yeah needs to be one path, or a group.

Answer (score 1):

In Inkscape path effects can only be applied if you select a vector object first. If you don't have one selected, then it won't show any path effects or even let you hit the menu button to get to the dropdown.  Also it won't work if you have selected a raster image (because it's not vector). It won't work for a text object either, unless you first convert it to vector outlines using *Path > Object to Path*.

There is a trick/hack for text objects though, without having to convert to outlines. If you clone the text, you can apply a path effect to the clone.

The Simplify Path effect is shown here

[image]

Comment: Thank you, all. This is very helpful.

Comment: Ok. Got it to show the simplify path effect, but still do not see "Apply"...

Comment: @DavidLay There's no Apply.  These path effects are live.  If you want to bake in the effect, do *Path > Object to Path*. This will convert the effect to actual vector paths with the modifications applied.  Note that this is destructive and one you do that, you can no longer adjust the effect in a live fashion.

Comment: @DavidLay In Inkscape 1.3, there's also a drop down menu next to the delete/trashcan icon in the path effects panel. You can choose the "Flatten" option. It will do the same.